# Is there a parser generator for ruby that can generate a parser with no gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby, parsing, antlr, peg

In an effort to make a DSL I have written backwards-compatible with **ruby** 1.8 I need to do some (relatively straightforward) parsing on the source strings. I could probably do directly with string munging, but in the interest of future maintainability I wanted to investigate first to see what it would take to use a proper parser generator.

The role of this DSL, however, puts an unusual constraint on what **ruby** gems I can use. The DSL is part of an **Xcode** project that's distributed with **CocoaPods**, and **CocoaPods** is not really about managing **ruby** dependencies in the build environment.

What this means is, my **ruby** DSL is effectively restricted to the gems that ship pre-installed on **Mac OS X 10.8**.

**SO**, my question: Is there a **ruby** parser generator out there that generates "stand-alone" **ruby** code as its final output? Meaning **ruby** code that does not `require` anything that's not part of core **ruby**?

I have looked at the (sparse) documentation for **ANTLR for Ruby**, but it (understandably) does not address my question. And from my quick glimpse at **treetop**, it does seem to use a support package bundled as a gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further searching I came across the **rexical** gem, which is itself a renamed-and-slightly-maintained version of **rex**. This is an old-school lexer-generator thats only dependency is on **racc/parser**, which has been part of **ruby-core** for long enough that I don't have to worry about it.

The documentation is sparse, but there were enough blog posts touching on the topic that I was able to get what I needed working.

In case you're curious enough to have read this far, here is my example **.rex** specification:

```
require 'generator'

class OptionSpecsLexer
rules
  \d+(\.\d*)            { [:number, text] }
  \w+:                  { [:syntax_hash_key, ":#{text[0, text.length - 1]} =>"] }
  \:\w+                 { [:symbol, text] }
  \w+\(                 { [:funcall_open_paren, text] }
  \w+                   { [:identifier, text] }
  \"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"     { [:string, text] }
  =>                    { [:rocket, text] }
  ,                     { [:comma, text] }
  \{                    { [:open_curly, text] }
  \}                    { [:close_curly, text] }
  \(                    { [:open_paren, text] }
  \)                    { [:close_paren, text] }
  \[                    { [:close_square, text] }
  \]                    { [:close_square, text] }
  \\\s+                 { }
  \n                    { [:eol, text] }
  \s+                   { }

inner

  def enumerate_tokens
    Generator.new { |token|
      loop {
        t = next_token
        break if t.nil?
        token.yield(t)
      }
    }
  end

  def normalize(source)
    scan_setup source
    out = ""
    enumerate_tokens.each do |token|
      out += ' ' + token[1]
    end
    out
  end

end
```

This lexer understands just enough **ruby** syntax to preprocess specifications written in my **vMATCodeMonkey** DSL, replacing the new *keyword*-style hash key syntax with the old *rocket operator* syntax. [This was done to allow **vMATCodeMonkey** to work on un-updated **Mac OS X 10.8** which still ships with a deprecated version of **ruby**.]